# if allah is unchanging how can he do actions or have knowledge of infinite things?

Tags: aqidah

wouldn't something unchanging be inert?if he has eternal action,then that would mean eternal infinite regress of events in the past wouldn't it?Imam ghazali speaks against this.

also how can his knowledge be omniscient if its impossible to know a true infinity of events in the future?since a true rather than potential infinity doesn't exist?

Comment: You should share your evidences for your basic claims that you build your "opinion" about Allah his attributes and essence etc. upon. Else none could really address your issues nor answer them adequately. Just saying X said so isn't much helpful. A certain part of Muslims (sects) doesn't know al Ghazaly nor his views or is even denying and condemning them as a wrong 'aqidah.

Answer (score 0):

Allah has infinite knowledge , since if he was finite he wouldn't be God,

Allah keeps on creating, by saying Allah doesn't change, what's meaant is his attributes , his knowledge, Allah is beyond time , so we shouldn't try to think theses things too much .

God cannot be finite , ofcourse, Maybe in some other sense , but try to understand. He has infinite Power

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9571/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-hadeeth-do-not-inveigh-against-time-waqt-for-allaah-is-time-waqt

> Say, "If the sea were ink for [writing] the words1 of my Lord, the sea would be exhausted before the words of my Lord were exhausted, even if We brought the like of it in [continual] supplement."
> 18:109

Footnote
The words of Allāh's unlimited knowledge or words describing His attributes and His grandeur or praise of Him (subḥānahu wa taʿālā).